Trying to start application at startup using systemd not working
I am trying to run a program at startup and after investigation it seems systemd is the most portable way to go.  I have been testing on Rocky Linux.
The steps I took are:

Created the following C++ application:

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <thread>

std::string get_current_time_and_date()
{
  auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  auto in_time_t = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);

  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << std::put_time(std::localtime(&in_time_t), "%Y-%m_%d %X");
  return ss.str();
}

int main()
{
  // open log file for append
  std::ofstream logger("awesome.log", std::ios::app);

  while(true)
  {
      logger << get_current_time_and_date() << std::endl;
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(60));
  }
}

built as:
g++ awesome.cpp -o awesome
then sudo cp awesome /opt/awesomecompany/awesome
I then created a /opt/awesomecompany/start.sh script:
#!/bin/bash

echo "Starting Awesome app">>awesome.log
/opt/awesomecompany/awesome &
echo "awesome is now running as background task"

chmod +x start.sh
I then created a unit file: /etc/systemd/system/awesome.service
[Unit]
Description=Awesome systemd service.

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash /opt/awesomecompany/start.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

sudo chmod 644 /etc/systemd/system/awesome.service
sudo systemctl enable awesome
I then rebooted but the program is not running.  Nothing in ps -a and don't see anything logged to awesome.log
And:
sudo systemctl status awesome
awesome.service - Awesome systemd service.
    Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/awesome.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
    Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2024-06-13 11:30:11 BST; 6 min ago
  Duration: 77ms
  Main PID: 680 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
       CPU: 7ms

Jun 13 11:30:11 localhost systemd[1]: Started Awesome systemd service..
Jun 13 11:30:11 localhost bash[680]: awesome is running as background task
Jun 13 11:30:11 localhost systemd[1]: awesome.service: Deactivated successfully.

Is it because it sees the start.sh script return - ie it just runs the awesome program and exits?  What is the usual way to make this work?

I'm not sure, but this feels like there's a disconnect between what Type=simple really means and what you hope it means! In your example,you assume your program will continue to run after bash has exited. That might not be the case (and even if so, you'd probably want Type=forking, and you should write the PID of the forked-off awesome process to a file specified by PIDFile). Have you checked with the exact wording in man systemd.servive's section on Type= that you're getting what you're expecting?

Generally, I'd remove the start.sh; it does nothing useful, and it makes it impossible for systemd to directly monitor your process; you'd want Type=exec.

I agree that start.sh is not needed, just start the binary directly. If started from the script, at least remove the ampersand (&). As it is now, the script starts the app in background, but systemd thinks the bash process is the main process of the service, and as soon as the shell exits, systemd thinks you're done and loses control of the service. That's why you see the "code exited, status success" message.

In case anyone makes the same mistakes I made in getting this to work, here is how I resolved the problem.  Thanks for the comments.
[Unit]
Description=Awesome systemd service.

[Service]
Type=exec
ExecStart=/opt/awesomecompany/awesome

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

As discussed in the comments, the script to start the program was running the program in the background so the script would have quickly terminated and I so systemd assumes the program has stopped.
If you don't need any specific startup processing, easiest thing to do is simply run the program directly as above.
The use of Type = exec is a small tweak.
